# How to mock __init__

Tags: python-2.7, mocking

i have a class as:

```
class MainClass:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

class UserClass:
    def some_function():
        instance = MainClass("Hello")
```

Now i want to test whether class MainClass is called with data = "Hello".
How this can be done.
I searched for this but couldn't make out anything.

Comment: Never seen anyone Mock construction in my entire career. What are you trying to test? Given MainClass("Hello") instance.Data == "Hello" ? A Mock is not your class, so if you mocked it's construction you haven't tested your class's construction...

Comment: I have a app that will call MainClass at the end after processing all the other data and will pass the processed data to MainClass. I want to test whether the data which is reached to MainClass is proper

Comment: Not clear mate, do you want to test whether MainClass init does what it should, or do you want to test whether some_function initialises a MainClass, two different tests them.

Comment: I have two things one is a app which processes user input data into some specific format and after formatting that data it will pass it to 2nd part that is MainClass. Now i want to test whether that MainClass' construction is called with proper data. so that i will be assured that my app is working properly.

Comment: We are talking past each other. Unit tests would be proper data is produced, MainClass is constructed, MainClass Constructor does what it should. End to end is an integration test not a unit test.  You could MockMainClass to see if it's constructor is called from some_function but that would not involve mocking init as such.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the motivations behind the need to test a class' `__init__` method (as debated in the comments to the original question), the OP is asking "*whether class MainClass is called with data = "Hello". How this can be done*" and I'm going to answer just that.

First, yes, it can be done.

Next, how it can be done:

- patch your class `__init__` method using `patch.object`
- as the new method pass a `Mock`
- check that the mocked method has been called with the expected data

In code:

```
from mock import Mock, patch

def test_init_called_with_specific_data():
    data = "Hello"
    with patch.object(MainClass, "__init__", Mock(return_value=None)):
        instance = MainClass(data)
        instance.__init__.assert_called_with(data)
```

Depending on the application you might want to use a `MagicMock` that mocks the entire class, magic methods included (magic methods being those starting and ending with a double underscore, aka "dunder" methods).